# Datasource of the rendering is always created in the English language but not in the current page language

Tags: sxa

I defined two languages in Sitecore: `en` and `nl-NL`.
Also I created simple rendering and trying to create datasource (datasource template has Standard Values for en and `nl-NL` languages with predefined values for fields) for my rendering  in Experience Editor mode.

When I'm creating datasource item in Experience Editor and context page language is `en` - I can see that datasource was created for `en` version

**Problem is:**

When I'm creating datasource item in Experience Editor and context page language is `nl-NL` - I can see that datasource was created only for `en` version, but not for `nl-NL`

Sitecore 9 Update 1, SXA 1.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sitecore Support confirmed that it's a bug and prepared patch **Sitecore.Support.254850** for resolve this issue.

https://github.com/sitecoresupport/Sitecore.Support.254850/releases